# OpenLayers 3 custom resolution

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I've tried using a simply XYZ grid but with some custom resolution :

```
var mapExtent = [0.000000, -8192.000000, 8192.000000, 0.000000];
var mapMinZoom = 0;
var mapMaxZoom = 7;
var mapMaxResolution = 1.000000;
var tileExtent = [0.000000, -8192.000000, 8192.000000, 0.000000];

var mapResolutions = [];
for (var z = mapMaxZoom; z >= mapMinZoom; z--) {
   mapResolutions.push(1024*(z+1));  
}
```

I had a pic, broken it down in 8 zoom levels, all 256x256 tiles, resolutions : 1024 * k, where k = [1,8].
For some reason, it looks really wierd, only shows part of the map, starts at maxzoom and when zoomed out only shows 1/4 of the image ( the top left corner and I can't move the picture at all ).

Any clue why this is happening ? How can I fix it?